# creating array of objects from array of arrays, using static method call (PHP)

Tags: php, class, static

I have an array like this:

```
// Define pages
$pages = array(
    "home" => array(
        "title" => "Home page",
        "icon" => "home"
    ),
    "compositions" => array(
        "title" => "Composition page",
        "icon" => "music"
    ),
);
```

And what I am trying to accomplish is, having:

```
$navigation = Utils::makeNavigation($pages);
```

, create `$navigation` as an array of objects, so that I can parse it in my view
like this:

```
foreach($navigation as $nav_item){
    echo $nav_item->page; // home(1st iter.), compositions(2nd iter.)
    echo $nav_item->title;// Home page, Composition page
    echo $nav_item->icon; // home, music
}
```

Is `static` `Util-like-class` approach good for this kind of problem?

**EDIT**

I came up with something like this, does this seem ok?

```
<?php
class Utils {

    protected static $_navigation;

    public static function makeNavigation($pages = array()){

        if (!empty($pages)){
            foreach ($pages as $page => $parts) {
                $item = new stdClass;
                $item->page = $page;

                foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
                    $item->$key = $value;
                }
                self::$_navigation[] = $item;
            }
        return self::$_navigation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your criterias to separate "good" from "bad"?

Comment: What is "ok"? Can it be measured objectively? What is "ok" for one, is "not ok" for another. It's "not ok" for me - I'd use `array_map` instead. Does this count as an answer?

Comment: Could you give small example regarding my situation, on how would you do it using `array_map`?

Comment: I would use it instead of a loop

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are creating the array manually in your code, just cast to objects:

```
$pages = array(
    "home" => ( object ) array(
        "title" => "Home page",
        "icon" => "home"
    ),
    "compositions" => ( object ) array(
        "title" => "Composition page",
        "icon" => "music"
    ),
);
```

That will allow accessing them like objects:

```
$pages->home->title;
```

or looping through them like this:

```
for ( $pages as $pageName => $pageObject ) echo $pageName . " has title: " . $pageObject->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would include the creation as a static member of the class to keep the class specific code together:

```
class NavItem
{
//  Static member does not require an object to be called
static function create ($def)
{
    $ret = array ();
    foreach ($def as $idx=>$navDef)
        $ret [$idx] = new NavItem ($navDef);
    return $ret;
}
function __construct ($def)
{
    // Do something more specific with the current def (title, icon array)
    $this->param = $def;
}

function display ()
{
    //  Simple example
    echo $this->param ['title'];
    echo $this->param ['icon'];
}
    var                     $param;
};

//  Using your pages array as above
$pages = NavItem::create ($pages);
foreach ($pages as $idx=>$page)
    $page->display ();
```

Comment: That's not what I was trying to accomplish, I gave en example on what I would like ending up with. Having all 3 properties in one `itterable` object. You missed `page` attribute that I also need.